# Confused :escape \ or not /\ in javascript's regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, escaping

To extract html part from string :

With escape in regular expression:

```
RegExp('<script type="text\/javascript">[^]+<\/script>');
```

```js
var content = '<p>test</p><script type="text/javascript">somany lines and \n\
                 so many lines</scr' + 'ipt>';
var reg_escape = new RegExp('<script type="text\/javascript">[^]+<\/scr' + 'ipt>');
var onlyHtml = content.replace(reg_escape,"");
alert(onlyHtml);
```

Without escape in regular expression:

```
RegExp('<script type="text/javascript">[^]+</script>');
```

```js
var content = '<p>test</p><script type="text/javascript">somany lines and \n\
                 so many lines</scr' + 'ipt>';
var reg_escape = new RegExp('<script type="text/javascript">[^]+</scr' + 'ipt>');
var onlyHtml = content.replace(reg_escape,"");
alert(onlyHtml);
```

Both of them get the same result--extracting html part only.
Now there is a whole html file with escape  in regular expression:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style type='text/css'>
    div#html{
        border:1px solid red;
        height:80px;
        width:80px;
        float:left;
    }
    div#content{
        clear:both;
        width:400px;
        height:400px;
        border:1px solid black;
    }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='html'>html</div>
    <div id='content'>
    </div>        
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    var html_string = document.body.innerHTML;
    var content = document.getElementById('content');
    var ob_html = document.getElementById('html');
    var reg = new RegExp('<script type="text\/javascript">[^]+<\/script>');
    var onlyHtml = html_string.replace(reg,"");
    alert(onlyHtml);
   </script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Save as `with_escape.html` and open it with a browser,you extract html part from `with_escape.html`.

There is a whole html file without escape  in regular expression:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style type='text/css'>
    div#html{
        border:1px solid red;
        height:80px;
        width:80px;
        float:left;
    }
    div#content{
        clear:both;
        width:400px;
        height:400px;
        border:1px solid black;
    }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='html'>html</div>
    <div id='content'>
    </div>        
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    var html_string = document.body.innerHTML;
    var content = document.getElementById('content');
    var ob_html = document.getElementById('html');
    var reg = new RegExp('<script type="text/javascript">[^]+</script>');
    var onlyHtml = html_string.replace(reg,"");
    alert(onlyHtml);
   </script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Save as `without_escape.html` and open it with a browser,you get can't extract html part from `without_escape.html`.An error ocurrs:

[image]

Why in previous code snippet ,it's no matter whether to escape `\` as `/\` or not?

Comment: There is no difference because `"\/"` is `/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a JS string literal `/` and `\/` mean exactly the same thing.

In an HTML document `</script>` is an end tag for a script element, but `<\/script>` isn't.

The version without the `\` fails when you embed it in an HTML document because you are terminating the script element in the middle of an expression.